# Inverse the result of a regex

Tags: java, regex

My string should begin with Test and end with max 3 digits. The rest I like to replace with a empty string.

```
"Test_123Text".replaceAll("Test\\d{1,3}","");
```

How to replace the inverse string of "Test_\d{1,3}" from the example above?

Comment: Maybe this will work "Test_123Text".replaceAll("Test*\\d{1,3}","");

Answer (score 0):

Use capturing groups.

```
"Test_123Text".replaceAll("^(Test).*?(\\d{1,3})$","$1$2");
```

> and end with max 3 digits

```
"Test_123Text".replaceAll("^Test.*?(?<!\\d)(\\d{1,3})$","Test$1");
```

Comment: I think an inline dotall modifier can be useful here, too.